# Json to HTML Table Convert using AngularJS Ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can anyone help me in coming up with HTML table for JSON using Angular JS Ng-Repeat (Please see the HTML table format as below)

Assuming Angular JS get the JSON from a file and Object will be **PersonEvents**

so I will use  list in PersonEvents in AngulaJS view

**JSON**

```
{
  "PersonEvent": {
    "Body": {
      "Persons": {
        "CurrentPersons": {
          "Service": [
            {
              "-PersonID": "TS029",
              "PersonChangeActivity": "NoChange",
              "Define": {
                "PersonPCProduct": {
                  "-pn": "8000065"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "-PersonID": "TS023",
              "PersonChangeActivity": "NoChange",
              "Define": {
                "PersonPCProduct": {
                  "-pn": "8000005",
                  "Business": "Voice"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "PersonChanges": {
          "PersonInstalls": {
            "Service": [
              {
                "-PersonID": "OT446",
                "PersonChangeActivity": "Install",
                "Define": {
                  "PersonPCProduct": {
                    "-pn": "2411",
                    "Business": "Video"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "-PersonID": "VD034",
                "PersonChangeActivity": "Install",
                "Define": {
                  "PersonPCProduct": {
                    "-pn": "2552",
                    "Business": "Video"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "PersonDisconnects": {
            "Service": [
              {
                "-PersonID": "VD034",
                "PersonChangeActivity": "Disconnect",
                "Define": {
                  "PersonPCProduct": {
                    "-pn": "2552",
                    "Business": "Video"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "-PersonID": "VP087",
                "PersonChangeActivity": "Disconnect",
                "Define": {
                  "PersonPCProduct": {
                    "-pn": "10400024",
                    "Business": "Video"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected HTML Table**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Current Persons<br></th>
    <th>PersonInstalls</th>
    <th>PersonDisconnects</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TS029,NoChange,8000065<br>TS023,NoChange,8000005</td>
    <td>OT446,Install,2411<br>VD034,Install,2552</td>
    <td>VD034,Disconnect,2552<br>VP087,Disconnect,10400024</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">                  
              <td ng-repeat="item in x.CurrentPersons.Service">
                 {{item["-PersonID"]}}, {{item.PersonChangeActivity}} <br>
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="name in x.PersonChanges.PersonInstalls.Service">
                 {{name["-PersonID"]}},{{name.PersonChangeActivity}},{{name.Define.PersonPCProduct["-pn"]}} <br>
                </td>
                 <td ng-repeat="disconnect in x.PersonChanges.PersonDisconnects.Service">
                 {{disconnect["-PersonID"]}},{{disconnect.PersonChangeActivity}},{{disconnect.Define.PersonPCProduct["-pn"]}} <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LasMXCdH19PhDxdV4fMt?p=preview)

Comment: I am getting  
 <td> TS029,NoChange<br></td><td>TS023,NoChange<br></td>

But I wanted
<td>TS029,NoChange,8000065<br>TS023,NoChange,8000005</td>

Can you plese check

Comment: I wanted a table this way

Comment: Really thanks for the help Sajeetharan .. I just struggling in this way so was asking you. BTW u helped me last time AngulaJS I am really thankful for that as well :)

Comment: tell me what you need exactly

Comment: I wanted to get  this way <td>TS029,NoChange,8000065<br>TS023,NoChange,8000005</td> but when i run the plnkr I am getting 
 <td>TS029, NoChange,8000065 <br></td><td>TS023, NoChange,8000005<br></td>

Which mean i dont wanted to get </td><td>  in middle I just wanted <br>

This is problem Sanhetharan.

Because of which table not reflecting properly. But Thanks I will try to use above and work for it.